# Receiving an error when using getServerSideProps in a Next.js application (TypeError: res.hasHeader is not a function)

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js

I've run into the error below when trying to use `getServerSideProps` to fetch data from an endpoint.

**Error:**

```
ERROR   TypeError: res.hasHeader is not a function
    at sendPayload (/var/task/pages/posts.js:2120:231)
    at renderReqToHTML (/var/task/pages/posts.js:6235:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

**Function:**

```
export const getServerSideProps : GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const API = 'http://myAPIEndpoint'
  const res = await fetch(API, {
                headers: {
                  'Id': '1234'
                }
              });
 
  const posts = await res.json()
 
  return{
    props: {
      posts
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been resolved in serverless-next.js@1.9.8. I ran into the same problem and found these issues in the serverless-next.js repo:

- https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/pull/342#issuecomment-609999944
- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11223

Upgrading to 1.9.8 fixed it for me:

```
#serverless.yml

myAppName:
  component: 'serverless-next.js@1.9.8'
```